# PDF Compression Techniques

Tags: java, pdf, compression, itext

I am trying to compress PDF document in Java. The original file size is 1.5-2 MB and we need to bring it down to less than 1 MB.  I tried using iText compression on it, however the results are not that effective and file size is still greater than 1 MB.

```
byte[] mergedFileContent = byteArrayOS.toByteArray();
reader = new PdfReader(mergedFileContent);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, byteArrOScomp);
stamper.setFullCompression();
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Has anyone worked on something similar? Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: What media / images does your pdf contain and how do you intend to compress them?

Comment: @Jankapunkt The pdf basically consists of text and tabular formatting on it. We don't have any high quality images being rendered on the pdf. I am just looking to reduce it to a size which could be less than 1 MB.

Comment: Are you bound to pdf stamper? As I can see it, it is not very clear in it's documentation what compression algorithm it uses. The [Adobe PDF specifications](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) shows different possible compression algorithms and methods. So if your lib does not offer you to choose from different compression methods you may switch to another lib.

Comment: You cannot set some random target size and expect software to compress *to that size* (or less). If it were possible, all compressed files should end up as 1 byte. See http://www.data-compression.com/theory.html.

Comment: @RadLexus Thanks for your response. We are not trying to set a target but trying to make sure that the output is within a limited range which is acceptable as per the current scenario. And i totally agree if it were possible then it would immensely improve storage. I just wish to find out if there are any better libraries as compared to iText which could provide a much better compression here. Please suggest !

Comment: @Jankapunkt Could you please suggest some libraries that work better than iText!!

Comment: @Nishant no offence but this should be part of your research competencies.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into the official iText examples, in particular the sample [HelloWorldCompression](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-12#475-helloworldcompression.java) is about applying different degrees of compression both at initial PDF creation time and as a post-processing step.

The following method from that sample may help you along.

```
public void compressPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
    stamper.getWriter().setCompressionLevel(9);
    int total = reader.getNumberOfPages() + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < total; i++) {
        reader.setPageContent(i, reader.getPageContent(i));
    }
    stamper.setFullCompression();
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

If you wonder how I found it: I googled for "itextpdf example full compression" and it was the second result. (The first find contains the same method but is not from the official iText site.)

Comment: The pdf is being processed using a third-party tool. And i have tried using all the different levels of compression, however stamper.setFullCompression(); still produces the best result of all.

Answer (score 0):

You could gzip, zip, etc. the file afterwards. It isn't really a PDF compression format, but if you are constrained and want better compression then compressing the entire thing may have good results since it can compress meta-level data.